# How to get multiple legend components for only one plot function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having a lot of trouble getting a legend working for the plot I'm working on right now. I just want a basic legend that says "Observed" and "Not Observed" for the yellow and grey dots, respectively. I don't know why I'm having so much trouble with this, and I know it's probably a dumb question, but I can't seem to find any answers online.

As this code is right now, it prints a legend with a component for every line in the data, even though there are only two unique values that can possibly occur:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches


filename = ("master.kkids.obslist")

data = np.loadtxt(filename,skiprows=14,dtype=str)

x = data[:,7]
y = data[:,8]
u = data[:,18]
v = data[:,19]
z = data[:,20]

r = u.astype(str)
s = v.astype(str)
t = z.astype(str)

colors = ["grey" if s == "N" else "yellow" for s in v]
labelf = ["Observed" if s == "N" else "Not Observed" for s in v]

x1 = x.astype(float)
y1 = y.astype(float)
x2 = x1*24/360

plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 26, 2.0))

plt.scatter(x2,y1,c=colors,label=labelf)
plt.ylabel('Declination' + " (" + u"\N{DEGREE SIGN}"+ ")")
plt.xlabel('Right Ascension (h)')

plt.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.savefig('foo.png')
```

Any help getting this legend working would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, using subplot and plotting each graph individually, labeling the desired plots, then showing the plots all at once using show, will give you more control. Have a look at the documentation for plt.legend.http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html

Comment: I figured as much, but I'm unsure of how to split the data into two different plots. I have my x and y data, and then a third column that determines which color the point is going to be.

Comment: I see. Maybe combing all the data you want labeled one way into one array, and all the rest into another, plotting and labeling the two new arrays appropriately is easiest. Sorry I'm on my mobile or I'd wrote or the code. Also in each of the new plots you can just specify the color. Again sorry for the lack of clarity. GL.

Comment: It's cool, I actually figured it out. Instead of having the colors defined in the function above, I just set a criteria for the x/y arrays for the Y/N in the 3rd column. That way I can just plot x1[yes] and x1[no], and set their colors individually from there. Sorry for the lack of jargon, I'm entirely self-taught in this.